# “More rigorous” way to minimize $\sqrt{1^2+a_1^2}+\sqrt{2^2+a_2^2}+\cdots+\sqrt{8^2+a_8^2}$, subject to $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_8=27$, for $a_n>0$

Tags: geometry, inequality, optimization

I have the following problem:

> Minimize the sum $$\sqrt{1^2+a_1^2}+\sqrt{2^2+a_2^2}+\cdots+\sqrt{8^2+a_8^2}$$ subject to $$a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_8=27$$
> for $a_n>0$.

The way I went about solving this is to interpret the given sum as the sum of the lengths of some line segments and noting how they become minimized when they all form a straight line. However, this “geometric” approach doesn’t sit right with me and I was wondering if there was a more general inequality describing this situation (something like AM-GM). Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\vec{u_i}=(i, a_i) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. By the (generalized) triangle inequality for the Euclidean norm we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^8 \sqrt{i^2+a_i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^8 \|u_i\|\geq \left\|\sum_{i=1}^8 u_i\right\|=\|(36, 27)\|=45$$
We can see that equality is achieved when setting $a_i = \frac{27}{36}i$ therefore $45$ is indeed the minimum. Your geometric observation is the well-known fact that triangle inequality becomes equality when the vectors are parallel!

Answer (score 2):

A more robust approach is to use calculus to find the minimum: Over $\{a : a_i > 0 \text{ for all } i\}$, you want to minimize
$$f(a) = \sqrt{1^2 + a_1^2} + \dots + \sqrt{8^2 + a_8^2}$$
subject to the constraint
$$g(a) = a_1 + \dots + a_8 = 27.$$
You can use the Lagrange multiplier theorem to do this. By the theorem, any local interior minimum or maximum $a$ along the constraint surface $A = \{a : a_i \geq 0, a_1 + \dots + a_8 = 27\}$ satisfies
$$f_{a_j}(a) = \lambda g_{a_j}(a)$$
for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
Thus
$$(j^2 + a_j^2)^{-1/2}a_j = \lambda,$$
$$a_1 + \dots + a_8 = 27.$$
From here you can deduce $a_i = c i$ from the first equation, then deduce $c = \frac{27}{1 + \dots + 8} = \frac{27}{36}$ from the second equation. Thus $a_i =  \frac{27}{36}i$ is the only possible candidate for an interior local minimum.

Now you have to argue that this $a$ is actually a minimum of $f$ over $A$. You could try to argue that the value of $f$ at $a$ is smaller than the minimum value of $f$ on the boundary of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this using convexity and Jensen's inequality. Observe that the function $f(t) = \sqrt{1+t^2}$ is convex (leaving the proof to you). Then rewriting your inequality and applying Jensen's inequality:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{i^2+x_i^2} =S\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{S}\sqrt{1+(x_i/i)^2}\geq S\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2},
$$
where $S = 1+2+\cdots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Now if you set $n=8$ then the RHS becomes $45$ with equality iff $x_1 = x_2/2 =\cdots = x_n/n$.

Comment: oooh I had actually thougt about using Jensen's inequality but the rewriting step didn't come to mind. Thanks for the insight!!

Comment: @Alp you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I am confused as to why you accept the accepted answer as it does not actually answer your question. You can prove the inequality:
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} + \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\geq \sqrt{(x+a)^2 + (y+b)^2}$$
by squaring and simplifying the result, which is:
$$\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)}\geq ax+by.$$
Above is just the classical form of Cauchy-Schwarz, or if you want then you can square and simplify again to get:
$$(bx-ay)^2\geq 0.$$
Then, you can apply this repeatedly/inductively to get the $n$ variable version. Note you can even see from the inequality condition, $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{x}{y}$, that it becomes equality when the two vectors are parallel.

You should note that the triangle inequality becomes a necessary axiom, once you "abstractize" enough e.g., normed vector space. Therefore, any "proof" of the triangle inequality can only be possible in a more specialized space, such $\mathbb{R}^n$ or an inner product space in general.